# Delete Surname in Orders and Returns page

Tags: sales

i have a question about the page Orders and Return:
is possible don't have the input Surname in the form? I tried to remove the input surname in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php but the form response that i had a error in the form.
Can you help me?
Thanks :)